# X-Content-Type-Options and Content-Type Headers, not working together

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, websphere, browser-security

In my web application I used owasp ZED Tool to check security vulnerability. I found that X-Content-Type-Options and Content-Type headers are not set.

In my cross filter, I have added the headers in HTTPResponse object

```
 @WebFilter("/*")
public class CrossFilter implements Filter {

    private static CoreLogger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstServlet.class);

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filter) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        try{
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse ) servletResponse ;
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

            filter.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }catch(Exception exc){
            logger.info(exc.getMessage());
            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.error(exc.getMessage(),exc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I am trying to access the application over browser, it shows me the source of HTML . I thought I have added text/plain was wrong and I tried text/html , but still error persists.

Could anyone help me out if the way I am doing is wrong ?

Comment: Tried with a cleared browser cache?

Comment: Also it's unrelated, but be careful with setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. You should only set this if you really need it, and consider possible consequences (like CSRF).